# accessing protected method in other package?

Tags: java, oop, access-modifiers

If I say

```
class A{
}
```

then it implicitly inherits Object class.So I am having the class as below:

```
class A{

       protected Object clone(){
       }  /// Here i am not overridning
       //All the other methods (toString/wait/notify/notifyAll/getClass)
}
```

Now Why cant I access the clone() method in Class B which is in the same package of class A.

```
Class B{
       A a = new A();
       a.clone();
       **
}
```

//** Says clone is protected in Object class . But I am not accessing Object's       clone method .Here I am invoking class A's clone method anyway which I havn't overloaded yet.

Comment: Your snippets are misleading.

    class A {}

and 
    class A {
      protected A clone() {}
    }

Are not equivalent at all. In the first one, you do not implement a's clone method while you do in snippet 2. The error you invoke does not shows with snippet 2.

Comment: It won't answer your question but in new API prefer static factory methods or copy constructors to clone().

Comment: what is meant by you comment `/// Here i am not overridning`? How are you not overriding it? In Object the `clone` method has exactly the same signature as `A.clone`, so it is overriding it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `protected` method is defined in the `java.lang.Object`, so you can't invoke it from another package - only from subclasses.

You are calling it on a a reference to `A` but it is a method of `java.lang.Object`, until you override it.

When overriding `clone()`, you should change the modifier to `public` and implement `Cloneable`. However using the `clone()` method is not a good idea, because it's very hard to implement it correctly. Use commons-beanutils to make shallow clones.

Make sure you make distinction between "overriding" and "overloading".

Comment: @Bozho: As I commented , I am not overriding clone method.But why I am not able to access that method from Class B?

Comment: @JavaUser - you definitely are overriding it in `A`!

Comment: @Bozho : No I am not overriding .I said the implicit meaning of inheriting from Object.

Comment: then remove the snippet where you show how you override it ;) and check my update - the first sentence

Comment: Anyway , I am only accessing the clone() method of my class A not Object.I didn't say Object obj.clone() ..I said A a.clone() ??!!!

Answer (score 1):

this perfectly work

```
class A{

       protected Object clone(){
           return this;
       }  
}

public class B{
       public B() {
           A a = new A();
           a.clone();
           System.out.println("success");
       }
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B();
    }

}
```

Comment: As I commented out I am not overriding clone method.Please remove the clone method from the above snippet and compile the code.

Comment: @JavaUser: that was not clear in your question so you have not a protected clone() in your A object it stays as a Object protected method and as such can't be called outside of the java.lang package